# Set an environment variable within a shell alias

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, alias

On my system, I've got two versions of Java installed - some programs require Java 7, some require Java 8.

Java 8 is my system default, so when I've been running the Java 7 commands, I've been using:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.*.jdk/Contents/Home/ \
java_7_program
```

I want to set an alias so I can instead write

```
j7 java_7_program
```

I've defined:

```
alias j7='JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.*.jdk/Contents/Home/'
```

But then running `j7 java -version` produces:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (search for "Aliases") states that this is done as a direct substitution. Is there a reason as to why this isn't working?

`bash --version` prints `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0)`

A more isolated example (minus the java):

```
$ alias foo='BAR=baz'
$ type foo
foo is aliased to `BAR=baz'
$ foo echo $BAR
[blank line]
```

Comment: Try `foo env` and you will see that BAR is set to baz. Also try `foo /bin/echo $BAR` and that should work. The difference is that *echo* is a shell builtin, so explicitly running the binary does the right thing.

Comment: Regarding your edit: As I already said, when you type `foo echo $BAR`, then `BAR` isn't set in the current shell, only in `echo`'s environment; and `$BAR` is expanded _before_ `echo` is run. Try any of these and you'll see it works: 1. type `foo` on its own line, and `echo $BAR` afterwards or, equivalently `foo; echo "$BAR"`; 2. `foo eval 'echo "$BAR"'`; 3. (somehow similar) `foo bash -c 'echo "$BAR"'`.

Comment: Ok, there were a couple of problems here. One is the problem I was asking about (why isn't an alias setting the variable?), and the confounding factor was that running `java` was using `/bin/java`, which was using 1.8 irrespective of the `JAVA_HOME` variable.

Comment: Re-reading all this, it seem your problem just comme from use of quotes `'`!  Just whipe quotes: `alias j7=JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.*.jdk/Contents/Home/` could work fine!

Comment: @F.Hauri Doesn't work for me. If you've executed this more than once though (i.e. `j7 ; j7 echo $JAVA_HOME`) then it works.

Comment: @F.Hauri what happened to your answer? It didn't directly answer the question but some of the stuff about functions was still useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering your isolated example:

when you do something like this:

```
bar=foo my_command
```

then `bar` is set in `my_command`'s environment (and is not seen by the current shell). Hence, when you do:

```
bar=stuff
bar=foo my_command "$bar"
```

since the expansion of `$bar` *occurs before `my_command` is executed*, then it's like doing:

```
bar=foo my_command stuff
```

since the `$bar` is expanded *before* my_command is forked. That explains the `[blank line]` you obtain in your example:

```
$ alias foo='BAR=baz'
$ type foo
foo is aliased to `BAR=baz'
$ foo echo $BAR
[blank line]
```

---

Just for fun, try these:

```
$ alias foo=BAR=baz
$ BAR=something
$ foo echo "$BAR"
something
```

makes sense?

```
$ alias foo=BAR=baz
$ foo eval 'echo "$BAR"'
baz
```

this is because `BAR` is passed in `eval`'s environment, and then `echo "$BAR"` is expanded… with the expected value (note the single quotes!).

Similarly,

```
$ alias foo=BAR=baz
$ foo sh -c 'echo "$BAR"'
baz
```

Comment: Thanks. Worth noting that alias foo='BAR=baz ;' works as well.

Comment: but did you not said ***`eval` is evil!*** ??

Comment: @F.Hauri: no I didn't `:)`… it's not really evil in this case (it's as evil/good as `sh` in the last example).

Answer (score 2):

## Using `env`

You can set environmental with the `env` utility.

```
alias foo='env - X=42 perl -E"say \$ENV{X}"'
```

This sets an alias `foo` which declares the environmental variable `X` and initializes it to `42` before executing `perl` and instructing it to print out the environmental variable `X`.

Answer (score 1):

The `jdk1.7.*.jdk` bit is probably the problem. If I put an explicit version in it works fine

You can use `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` to get the latest 1.7 version installed.

So to redo your alias, try:

```
alias j7='JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`'
```

Note the back ticks around the *java_home* bit which will then execute the command to generate the correct path to set *JAVA_HOME* to.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. As a reduced example: `alias foo='BAR=baz' ; foo echo $BAR` prints a blank line.

Comment: @FabianTamp `alias foo='BAR=baz'` and `foo` and `echo "$BAR"` on three separate lines (well, only the alias declaration needs to be on a separate line).

Comment: @FabianTamp I doubt it doesn't work. What is your shell? did you really enter all three commands on three separate lines?

Comment: Yep. copy-pasted the output in here too but it got messed up by newline stripping. `$ alias foo='BAR=baz'` `$ type foo`
`foo is aliased to 'BAR=baz'` `$ foo echo $BAR` [blank line]

Comment: Fabian, I think it is because echo is inside another shell, and normally shell variables are not passed through. What if you try my alias and do `j7 java -version` - this works on my Mac running 10.10.5, with bash version 3.2.57.

Comment: @FabianTamp You didn't proceed as I told you. I told you _on three separate lines_. When you type `foo echo $BAR`, it's like typing `BAR=baz echo $BAR`: the `BAR` variable is only in `echo`'s environment, not in the current shell, so the expansion `$BAR` will expand to whatever `BAR` is set in the current shell (which likely isn't set).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Oh, got it. That explains why it works with a script, but not if I write `JAVA_HOME="..." java -version` directly. Thanks. Could you make that into an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1):

#### Shell aliases could not be used to execute anything before setting environment.

Shell aliases could only hold plain commands, no *jocker* nor *sub commands*

For doing things like this, you have to write a *wrapper* script or at least a *function*.

```
sudo cat >/usr/local/bin/j7 <<<eof
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.*.jdk/Contents/Home/
java $@
eof
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/j7
```

or add this function definition to your `.bashrc`:

```
j7() {
  export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.*.jdk/Contents/Home/
  java $@
}
```

#### Real usefull bash wrapper

Something like:

```
j7 () {
    local JLIBROOT dir
    # JLIBROOT=/usr/lib/jdk
    JLIBROOT=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
    while read dir && [ "$dir" = "${dir//1.7.}" ] ;do
        :
      done < <(
          /bin/ls -1trd $JLIBROOT/*
    )
    if [ "$dir" != "${dir//1.7.}" ] ;then
          export JAVA_HOME=$dir/Contents/Home
          java $@
      else
          echo "Version 1.7 not found in '$JLIBROOT'."
      fi
}
```

could work on my Linux desktop...

Comment: Why do you say that a shell alias can't be used to modify environment? because it can… `alias abc='PATH=somewhere'` then `abc` then `declare -p PATH`… also works in POSIX shells (but not with `declare` to see the variable, obviously).